# How do I contribute code to Ubuntu so that Ubuntu devs have to expend a minimum of effort in integrating it?

Tags: launchpad, development, canonical, community

I have submitted a few bug reports over the years, most have never been closed (not closed fixed, anyway). I think I could speed this process a bit if I submitted patches. However:

- How do I submit code? Would just `diff` output do? Should I create a Launchpad project branching from the corresponding Ubuntu project?

  If this were on Github, I'd do a fork-and-pull-request. On Launchpad, there seems to be a parallel as documented in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/382839/158442).
- Are there conventions? Something like the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/index.html)?  How does this apply to non-code submissions, like documentation in the form of manpages, etc.?
- Are there special licensing requirements? IIRC the FSF requires that ownership of code contributions to FSF-copyrighted GNU software be [transferred to them](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/why-assign.en.html). Does Canonical have some such requirement?
- Is Launchpad sufficient as a medium of communication, or do I have to post on mailing lists as well (maybe ubuntu-devel, maybe some other list)?
- Should I add unit tests to code that I touch and submit those tests as well, assuming they aren't tested already?

This question applies to contributing code to software that's purely from Ubuntu (like the Ubiquity installer or the Ubuntu manpages repository) or patches for third party software to fix regressions that are unlikely to be fixed upstream (for example, Ubuntu maintained patches for GNOME Terminal). Essentially, work that Canonical devs maintain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I submit a patch to a Launchpad project?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372654/how-do-i-submit-a-patch-to-a-launchpad-project)

Comment: See also http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/contributors and http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing

Comment: Even if it is not like to be done here, I will give you a link to the site from ubuntu wiki where is explained how to contribute code to ubuntu:

[ContributeToUbuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ContributeToUbuntu#Writing_Code)